# Can't open my next screen in android app after 5 sec

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I m new to android programming 
 I was trying to develop a simple program in which a blank screen appears 
and after  5 sec my main activity starts 
but the problem is when I start app after 5 - 6 sec it shows error 
I programmed for xml and my layout is correct 
my app platform is 2.2 froyo 
and I m running it on 2.3.6
the main activity is an add one subtract one activity 
Please tell me what's wrong it happened to me in many programs

code for the activity first after this main activity starts

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash); //splash is a blank activity which changes after 5 sec
    Thread timer = new Thread () {
        public void  run(){

            try{
                sleep(5000);    
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                Intent newtask = new Intent("com.example.newscreentask.newacivity"); 
                startActivity(  newtask);

            }
        }

    };
    timer.start();
```

}
}

Comment: You have to provide your code and the logcat output.

Comment: try Intent newTask= new Intent(MainActivity.this, newActivity.class);

Comment: Tip: Unless your app needs to download/read some preliminary data before it can run, splashscreens are not generally recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
Intent newtask = new Intent("com.example.newscreentask.newacivity"); 
                startActivity(  newtask);
```

to:

```
Intent newtask = new Intent(this,newacivity.class); 
                startActivity(  newtask);
```

Also use handler.postDelayed instead

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Intent newtask = new Intent(MainActivity.this,newacivity.class); 
                    startActivity(  newtask);
                }
            }, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

A really good tutorial relating to this is
http://www.onlymobilepro.com/2013/01/16/android-beginner-creating-splash-screen/

It shows you how to create a splash screen that displays for a certain amount of time before showing your main activity.